# Checking for NaN presence in a container

Tags: python, python-3.x, containers, equality, nan

NaN is handled perfectly when I check for its presence in a list or a set. But I don't understand how. [UPDATE: no it's not; it is reported as present if the identical instance of NaN is found; if only non-identical instances of NaN are found, it is reported as absent.]

1. I thought presence in a list is tested by equality, so I expected NaN to not be found since NaN != NaN.
2. hash(NaN) and hash(0) are both 0. How do dictionaries and sets tell NaN and 0 apart?
3. Is it safe to check for NaN presence in an arbitrary container using `in` operator? Or is it implementation dependent?

My question is about Python 3.2.1; but if there are any changes existing/planned in future versions, I'd like to know that too.

```
NaN = float('nan')
print(NaN != NaN) # True
print(NaN == NaN) # False

list_ = (1, 2, NaN)
print(NaN in list_) # True; works fine but how?

set_ = {1, 2, NaN}
print(NaN in set_) # True; hash(NaN) is some fixed integer, so no surprise here
print(hash(0)) # 0
print(hash(NaN)) # 0
set_ = {1, 2, 0}
print(NaN in set_) # False; works fine, but how?
```

Note that if I add an instance of a user-defined class to a `list`, and then check for containment, the instance's `__eq__` method is called (if defined) - at least in CPython. That's why I assumed that `list` containment is tested using operator `==`.

EDIT:

Per Roman's answer, it would seem that `__contains__` for `list`, `tuple`, `set`, `dict` behaves in a very strange way:

```
def __contains__(self, x):
  for element in self:
    if x is element:
      return True
    if x == element:
      return True
  return False
```

I say 'strange' because I didn't see it explained in the documentation (maybe I missed it), and I think this is something that shouldn't be left as an implementation choice.

Of course, one NaN object may not be identical (in the sense of `id`) to another NaN object. (This not really surprising; Python doesn't guarantee such identity. In fact, I never saw CPython share an instance of NaN created in different places, even though it shares an instance of a small number or a short string.) This means that testing for NaN presence in a built-in container is undefined.

This is very dangerous, and very subtle. Someone might run the very code I showed above, and incorrectly conclude that it's safe to test for NaN membership using `in`.

I don't think there is a perfect workaround to this issue. One, very safe approach, is to ensure that NaN's are never added to built-in containers. (It's a pain to check for that all over the code...)

Another alternative is watch out for cases where `in` might have NaN on the left side, and in such cases, test for NaN membership separately, using `math.isnan()`. In addition, other operations (e.g., set intersection) need to also be avoided or rewritten.

Comment: Bottonline: to be on the safe side use: any(math.isnan(element) for element in list_)

Comment: @jsbueno: Yup... But that doesn't help with the set intersection problem; nor does it handle the case of `for x in cont1: if x in cont2 do something`... I'd say the bottom line is "be very afraid, and just hope you don't overlook something"

Comment: It won't help - and you have to agre there is no easy solution. You may use teh above loop to convert any NaN to strings reading "NaN" - these will compare unanbiguously.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Question #1: why is NaN found in a container when it's an identical object.

From the [documentation](http://docs.python.org/dev/reference/expressions.html#membership-test-details):

> For container types such as list, tuple, set, frozenset, dict, or
>   collections.deque, the expression x in y is equivalent to any(x is e
>   or x == e for e in y).

This is precisely what I observe with NaN, so everything is fine. Why this rule? I suspect it's because a `dict`/`set` wants to honestly report that it contains a certain object if that object is actually in it (even if `__eq__()` for whatever reason chooses to report that the object is not equal to itself).

Question #2: why is the hash value for NaN the same as for 0?

From the [documentation](http://docs.python.org/dev/reference/datamodel.html#object.__hash__):

> Called by built-in function hash() and for operations on members of
>   hashed collections including set, frozenset, and dict. **hash**()
>   should return an integer. The only required property is that objects
>   which compare equal have the same hash value; it is advised to somehow
>   mix together (e.g. using exclusive or) the hash values for the
>   components of the object that also play a part in comparison of
>   objects.

Note that the requirement is only in one direction; objects that have the same hash do not have to be equal! At first I thought it's a typo, but then I realized that it's not. Hash collisions happen anyway, even with default `__hash__()` (see an excellent explanation [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4867536/336527)). The containers handle collisions without any problem. They do, of course, ultimately use the `==` operator to compare elements, hence they can easily end up with multiple values of NaN, as long as they are not identical! Try this:

```
>>> nan1 = float('nan')
>>> nan2 = float('nan')
>>> d = {}
>>> d[nan1] = 1
>>> d[nan2] = 2
>>> d[nan1]
1
>>> d[nan2]
2
```

So everything works as documented. But... it's very very dangerous! How many people knew that multiple values of NaN could live alongside each other in a dict? How many people would find this easy to debug?..

I would recommend to make NaN an instance of a subclass of `float` that doesn't support hashing and hence cannot be accidentally added to a `set`/`dict`. I'll submit this to python-ideas.

Finally, I found a mistake in the documentation [here](http://docs.python.org/dev/reference/expressions.html#membership-test-details):

> For user-defined classes which do not define `__contains__()` but do
>   define `__iter__()`, `x in y` is true if some value `z` with `x == z` is
>   produced while iterating over `y`. If an exception is raised during the
>   iteration, it is as if `in` raised that exception.
>
> Lastly, the old-style iteration protocol is tried: if a class defines
>   `__getitem__()`, `x in y` is true if and only if there is a non-negative
>   integer index `i` such that `x == y[i]`, and all lower integer indices do
>   not raise `IndexError` exception. (If any other exception is raised, it
>   is as if `in` raised that exception).

You may notice that there is no mention of `is` here, unlike with built-in containers. I was surprised by this, so I tried:

```
>>> nan1 = float('nan')
>>> nan2 = float('nan')
>>> class Cont:
...   def __iter__(self):
...     yield nan1
...
>>> c = Cont()
>>> nan1 in c
True
>>> nan2 in c
False
```

As you can see, the identity is checked first, before `==` - consistent with the built-in containers. I'll submit a report to fix the docs.

Comment: You might be interested in this bugs.python.org issue: http://bugs.python.org/issue11945

Answer (score 2):

I can't repro you tuple/set cases using `float('nan')` instead of `NaN`.

So i assume that it worked only because `id(NaN) == id(NaN)`, i.e. there is no interning for `NaN` objects:

```
>>> NaN = float('NaN')
>>> id(NaN)
34373956456
>>> id(float('NaN'))
34373956480
```

And

```
>>> NaN is NaN
True
>>> NaN is float('NaN')
False
```

I believe tuple/set lookups has some optimization related to comparison of the same objects.

Answering your question - it seam to be unsafe to relay on `in` operator while checking for presence of `NaN`.  I'd recommend to use `None`, if possible.

---

Just a comment.  `__eq__` has nothing to do with `is` statement, and during lookups comparison of objects' ids seem to happen prior to any value comparisons:

```
>>> class A(object):
...     def __eq__(*args):
...             print '__eq__'
...
>>> A() == A()
__eq__          # as expected
>>> A() is A()
False           # `is` checks only ids
>>> A() in [A()]
__eq__          # as expected
False
>>> a = A()
>>> a in [a]
True            # surprise!
```

Comment: Wow this is weird. `float('nan')` is of type `float`, and `float` defines `__eq__`, so I don't understand how Python would fall back to using `id` instead to check for equality. Furthermore, when I followed your example, I found that `float('nan') in {float('nan'),1}` is `False`; so it appears that `set` uses `id` as a hash function instead of `hash`. Again, it's strange since `float('nan').__hash__` exists (and evaluates to `0`). It goes without saying that I agree 100% with your answer about `in` being unsafe for NaNs! :)

Comment: I understand (and expect) that `is` does not call `__eq__`. My concern is that `is` is used instead of `__eq__` to test if an object is present in a list. `is` may evaluate to False on identical strings or numbers, so it's not the right approach for membership tests.

Comment: @max but if it evaluates to `True`, the values of objects should **not** be treated as different.

Comment: For example, on my machine: `a = 1.2345678`; `b = 1.2345678`; `a is b` evaluates to `False`, but `a in (b,)` evaluates to `True` (it better!). Thus, it's clear that list membership is tested using `__eq__`, not `is`. It seems like a bug if Python uses `is` for some floats, but `__eq__` for others to test for membership.

Comment: In any case, +1 for discovering the strange behavior that I assumed can't possibly happen!