# How to troubleshoot pandas bug/feature?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas `DataFrame`, created this way:

```
import pandas as pd
wb = pd.io.parsers.ExcelFile('/path/to/data.xlsx')
df = wb.parse(wb.sheet_names[0])
```

The resulting dataframe has about a dozen columns, all having exactly the same length (about 150K).

For most columns, the following operation is nearly instantaneous

```
aset = set(df.acolumn)
```

But for some columns, the same operation, e.g.

```
aset = set(df.weirdcolumn)
```

takes > 10 minutes!  (Or rather, the operation fails to complete before the 10-minute timeout period expires.)  Same number of elements!

Stranger still:

```
In [106]: set([type(c) for c in df.weirdcolumn])
Out[106]: set([numpy.float64])

In [107]: df.weirdcolumn.value_counts()
Out[107]: []
```

It appears that the content of the column is all `nan`s

```
In [118]: all(np.isnan(df.weirdcolumn.values))
Out[118]: True
```

But this does not explain the slowdown mentioned before, because the following operation takes only a couple of seconds:

```
In [121]: set([np.nan for _ in range(len(data))])
Out[121]: set([nan])
```

I have run out of ways to find out the cause of the massive slowdown mentioned above.  Suggestions welcome.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One weird thing about nans is that they don't compare as equal. This means that "different" nan objects will be inserted separately for sets:

```
>>> float('nan') == float('nan')
False
>>> float('nan') is float('nan')
False
>>> len(set([float('nan') for _ in range(1000)]))
1000
```

This doesn't happen for your test of `np.nan`, because it's the same object over and over:

```
>>> np.nan == np.nan
False
>>> np.nan is np.nan
True
>>> len(set([np.nan for _ in range(1000)]))
1
```

This is probably your problem; you're making a 150,000 element set where *every single element* has the exact same hash (`hash(float('nan')) == 0`). This means that an inserting a new nan into a set that already has `n` nans takes at least `O(n)` time, so building a set of `N` nans takes at least `O(N^2)` time. 150k^2 is...big.

So yeah, nans suck. You could work around this by doing something like

```
nan_idx = np.isnan(df.weirdcolumn)
s = set(df.weirdcolumn[~nan_idx])
if np.any(nan_idx):
    s.add(np.nan)
```

Comment: How peculiar.  This would *kill* your performance.  Since each `nan` would hash to the same value, this is the absolute worst case scenario for collision resolution in the hash table.  I wonder if something like this could be exploited in python for nasty purposes ...

Comment: It's a little weird that `np.nan` doesn't get repeated in the set.  According to the glossary index for [hashable](http://docs.python.org/2/glossary.html), in order for an object to be hashable, all that is checked is `__eq__` (or `__cmp__`) and `__hash__`.

Comment: [The docs say](http://docs.python.org/dev/reference/expressions.html#membership-test-details): "For container types such as list, tuple, set, frozenset, dict, or collections.deque, the expression `x in y` is equivalent to `any(x is e or x == e for e in y)`." Presumably it checks `is` to shortcut the `==` test, since for most anything except nan `a is b` implies `a == b`, but that seems to be part of the semantics for the case when they're not.

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9904699/checking-for-nan-presence-in-a-container (where @MarkDickinson linked to the relevant quote), http://www.gossamer-threads.com/lists/python/python/922088, and http://bugs.python.org/issue11945.

Comment: Interesting.  That line isn't in the 2.7 docs which is what I usually peruse.

Comment: "So yeah, nans suck."  I'd say it's rather panda's use of nans that sucks.  numpy's nans are fine, for instance.

Comment: Eh, this isn't really pandas's fault. Numpy does the same thing in most cases, it just so happens that np.nan itself happens to not.

Comment: @kjo Just to illustrate that this really has nothing to do with pandas, note that `len(set(np.array([np.nan] * 10))) = 10`.