# How to configure pandas to use one numpy.nan, and not multiple, unique float('nan')s?

Tags: python, numpy, pandas

Is there a way to configure pandas to use `numpy.nan` as its NaN constant, or at least a single module-global constant `pandas.nan = float('nan')`, rather than [***a brand-new and unique `float('nan')`for each NaN it needs to represent?***](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14846147)

(Alternatively, is there any justification for *not* using a single, globally unique NaN constant, the way that `numpy` does?)

Comment: `numpy` doesn't use a single globally-unique NaN constant.  It has a constant, `numpy.nan`, which is predefined, but `len(set(np.array([np.nan]*10))) == 10`, and `f = np.array([np.nan]*2); print f[0] is f[1]` gives `False`.

Comment: I'm curious as to how it would help if there were only one NaN. But you could always write a function that takes a float and returns `numpy.nan` if the input was any NaN, and just the input otherwise, and call it on everything. That's more or less what pandas/numpy would have to do internally to support your request.

Comment: I understand that it would be a bit of an advantage because `(a is b) or (a == b)` logic would say NaN is the same. As it is, this wish is a bit crazy. Even if python used a singleton NaN, you are lost with different data types. Personally, I disagree with the fact that python does not raise a ValueError if you try to hash a NaN, but overall, NaNs are just very special, and if you have them, you have to be very careful with many things...