# Assigning a variable NaN in python without numpy

Tags: python, constants, nan

Most languages have a NaN constant you can use to assign a variable the value NaN.  Can python do this without using numpy?

Comment: C, C++, java, C#, ocaml, its a part of a lot of languages.

Comment: NaN, in C, is `NAN`; it's a constant defined in `math.h`, as of C99. (I feel it's fair to call the most recent standardized version of the language as that language. Thus "C" is C11.) (see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1923837/how-to-use-nan-and-inf-in-c); in C++, it's `NAN` as well, there's also `nan()`, `nanf()`, and `nanl()`, though I'm a bit less certain as to what they do. `double.NaN` in Java, `Double.NaN` in C#…

Answer (score 202, accepted):

Yes -- use [`math.nan`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/math.html#math.nan).

```
>>> from math import nan
>>> print(nan)
nan
>>> print(nan + 2)
nan
>>> nan == nan
False
>>> import math
>>> math.isnan(nan)
True
```

Before Python 3.5, one could use `float("nan")` (case insensitive).

Note that checking to see if two things that are NaN are equal to one another will always return false. This is in part because two things that are "not a number" cannot (strictly speaking) be said to be equal to one another -- see [What is the rationale for all comparisons returning false for IEEE754 NaN values?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1565164/646543) for more details and information.

Instead, use [`math.isnan(...)`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/math.html#math.isnan) if you need to determine if a value is NaN or not.

Furthermore, the exact semantics of the `==` operation on NaN value may cause subtle issues when trying to store NaN inside container types such as `list` or `dict` (or when using custom container types). See [Checking for NaN presence in a container](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9904699/646543) for more details.

---

You can also construct NaN numbers using Python's [decimal](https://docs.python.org/3/library/decimal.html) module:

```
>>> from decimal import Decimal
>>> b = Decimal('nan')
>>> print(b)
NaN
>>> print(repr(b))
Decimal('NaN')
>>>
>>> Decimal(float('nan'))
Decimal('NaN')
>>> 
>>> import math
>>> math.isnan(b)
True
```

`math.isnan(...)` will also work with Decimal objects.

---

However, you *cannot* construct NaN numbers in Python's [fractions](https://docs.python.org/3/library/fractions.html) module:

```
>>> from fractions import Fraction
>>> Fraction('nan')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Python35\lib\fractions.py", line 146, in __new__
    numerator)
ValueError: Invalid literal for Fraction: 'nan'
>>>
>>> Fraction(float('nan'))
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Python35\lib\fractions.py", line 130, in __new__
    value = Fraction.from_float(numerator)
  File "C:\Python35\lib\fractions.py", line 214, in from_float
    raise ValueError("Cannot convert %r to %s." % (f, cls.__name__))
ValueError: Cannot convert nan to Fraction.
```

---

Incidentally, you can also do `float('Inf')`, `Decimal('Inf')`, or [`math.inf`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/math.html#math.inf) (3.5+) to assign infinite numbers. (And also see [`math.isinf(...)`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/math.html#math.isinf))

However doing `Fraction('Inf')` or `Fraction(float('inf'))` isn't permitted and will throw an exception, just like NaN.

If you want a quick and easy way to check if a number is neither NaN nor infinite, you can use [`math.isfinite(...)`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/math.html#math.isfinite) as of Python 3.2+.

---

If you want to do similar checks with complex numbers, the `cmath` module contains a similar set of functions and constants as the `math` module:

- [`cmath.isnan(...)`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/cmath.html#cmath.isinf)
- [`cmath.isinf(...)`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/cmath.html#cmath.isinf)
- [`cmath.isfinite(...)`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/cmath.html#cmath.isfinite) (Python 3.2+)
- [`cmath.nan`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/cmath.html#cmath.nan) (Python 3.6+; equivalent to `complex(float('nan'), 0.0)`)
- [`cmath.nanj`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/cmath.html#cmath.nanj) (Python 3.6+; equivalent to `complex(0.0, float('nan'))`)
- [`cmath.inf`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/cmath.html#cmath.inf) (Python 3.6+; equivalent to `complex(float('inf'), 0.0)`)
- [`cmath.infj`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/cmath.html#cmath.infj) (Python 3.6+; equivalent to `complex(0.0, float('inf'))`)

Comment: Note that using float('nan) is 3x slower than using np.nan, and about 6.5 times slower than assigning nan = float('nan') once and then using the variable 'nan' for all following assignments (as suggested in abarnert's answer).

Answer (score 23):

```
nan = float('nan')
```

And now you have the constant, `nan`.

You can similarly create NaN values for decimal.Decimal.:

```
dnan = Decimal('nan')
```

Comment: This is the most efficient answer for multiple nan assignments:  That is, use float('nan') only once, and then use the assigned constant for all remaining assignments.  However if you are only doing one or two assignments of nan total, then using numpy.nan is fastest.

Comment: Python stupid API design, why not add a `float.nan` constant?

Answer (score 11):

Use `float("nan")`:

```
>>> float("nan")
nan
```

Answer (score 11):

You can get NaN from "inf - inf", and you can get "inf" from a number greater than 2e308, so, I generally used:

```
>>> inf = 9e999
>>> inf
inf
>>> inf - inf
nan
```

Comment: This answer downvoted unreasonably. I'm writing lots of small parsing tests in .txt files and using ast.literal_eval to get expected output part. It's impossible to call float('nan') there, and this answer was helpful for me.

Comment: @VitalikVerhovodov Just to point out, since Python 3.7, it is no longer possible to get a NaN value via `ast.literal_eval('1e999-1e999')`. See [bpo-31778](https://bugs.python.org/issue31778) for more details about the change. In the past `ast.literal_eval` appears to be able to add and subtract literals, but that was just due to the loose input validation for supporting evaluation of complex number literals. According to [its official documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ast.html#ast.literal_eval), `ast.literal_eval` is not designed for evaluating expressions involving operators.

Answer (score 8):

You can do `float('nan')` to get NaN.

Answer (score 2):

A more consistent (and less opaque) way to generate inf and -inf is to again use float():

```
>> positive_inf = float('inf')
>> positive_inf
inf
>> negative_inf = float('-inf')
>> negative_inf
-inf
```

Note that the size of a float varies depending on the architecture, so it probably best to avoid using magic numbers like 9e999, even if that is likely to work.

```
import sys
sys.float_info
sys.float_info(max=1.7976931348623157e+308,
               max_exp=1024, max_10_exp=308,
               min=2.2250738585072014e-308, min_exp=-1021,
               min_10_exp=-307, dig=15, mant_dig=53,
               epsilon=2.220446049250313e-16, radix=2, rounds=1)
```