# Python matplotlib - errorbar None values in series

Tags: python, matplotlib

I was trying to plot a series with error bars. The series may contain None values. When not using the errors - the series is plotted with no error. When trying to plot with the error bars - I get this error:

**My code is:**

```
x = [10.4, 11.12,11.3,None, 10.2,11.3]
y = [0.3, 1.2, 0.7, None, 1.1, 0.4]
y_err = [0.01, 0.04, 0.07, None, 0.01, 0.05] 

plt.plot(x,y, 'o', color='r') # this one works. I get a plot with 5 points. The null point is skipped
plt.errorbar(x,y,yerr=y_err) # this one doesn't work
```

**The error I get is:**

```
 TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'NoneType' and 'NoneType'
```

Is there any way to skip the null values in a series?

Thanks!

Comment: Are nones coming at the same index for x,y, and y_err?

Comment: And how big are the series normally? If you can simply filter out all the `None` values before plotting this could be easily done. Question is: do you have time and memory to do this?

Comment: @Sleepyhead - The Nones are coming at the same Index.

Comment: @Alexander - Pre filtering may be time consuming, and I was hoping to avoid that...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try using NaN rather than "None".

```
x = [10.4, 11.12,11.3,float('NaN'), 10.2,11.3]
y = [0.3, 1.2, 0.7, float('NaN'), 1.1, 0.4]
y_err = [0.01, 0.04, 0.07, float('NaN'), 0.01, 0.05] 
plt.plot(x,y, 'o', color='r')
plt.errorbar(x,y,yerr=y_err)
```

[Assigning a variable NaN in python without numpy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19374254/assigning-a-variable-nan-in-python-without-numpy)