# Remove list if nan is in a lists of lists

Tags: python, nan, nested-lists

I have a list of lists from a Pandas Data frame that contains nan values. I would like to remove all the lists that contain any nan values. Then plot the remaining values.

Example

```
test = [[1,2],[1,nan],[3,4]]
```

End Results

```
test = [[1,2],[3,4]]
```

If possible I would also like to make a graph from the end results using any plotting method. Any help you can provide on the manner would be greatly appreciated.

I apologize for the confusion that this question has caused, the list of lists was taken from a pandas data frame hence why nan is present in the example. I would like to keep the data frame as is and would like to work with the list of lists

Comment: That's not a valid Python syntax.

Comment: Are you using Pandas?

Comment: Please provide a [mcve] including reproducible samples of your input and output data, and _code_ for what you've already tried based on your own research

Comment: I apologize for the confusion that this question has caused, the list of lists was taken from a pandas data frame hence why nan is present in the example. I would like to keep the data frame as is and would like to work with the list of lists.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Removing values from list

#### Using `filter`

`nan` isnt proper Python syntax and is only used in the `Pandas` library. So I am going to replace this value with `None`.

we can use a `filter` function to remove any values within the list that contains a `nan` value.

```
test = list(filter(lambda x: None not in x, test))
```

#### Using list comprehension

Edit: Should be `x` instead of `test`. Thanks @fountainhead

> test = [x for x in test if None not in test]

```
test = [x for x in test if None not in x]
```

Both will return a list with values not containing `None` in them

## Plotting

We can use a library called `matplotlib` to plot a graph. For example, to create a scatter plot:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.scatter(x, y)
```

where plt.scatter takes in x values and y values for row and columns respectively. The full code is as follows:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

test = [[1,2],[1,None],[3,4]]
test = list(filter(lambda x: None not in x, test))

x = [x for x,y in test]
y = [y for x,y in test]

# Assume all first elements are x values second elements are y values
plt.scatter(x, y)
plt.show()
```

The example images is as follows

[image]

Comment: I don't think `test = [x for x in test if None not in test]` will work, since nan is different from `None`.

Comment: If the value is nan, then we can check if the np.nan from numpy is in the list instead

Comment: -- It still won't work. There seems to be a typo error in your list comprehension. The expression `[x for x in test if None not in test]` should be corrected to `[x for x in test if None not in x]`

Comment: @fountainhead yes! Thanks for pointing that out, will fix

Comment: If `np.nan` is present, your `filter()` solution and list-comprehension solutions will both work. If, however, `np.float64("NaN")` or `np.float32("NaN")` or `np.float("NaN")` is present, both your solutions will fail. For detailed reasons, refer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9904699/checking-for-nan-presence-in-a-container). To make your `filter()` solution work for these cases, the correct lambda should be `lambda x: not any(math.isnan(y) for y in x)`. To make your list comprehension work for these cases, refer my answer to OP.

Comment: In the lambda that I suggested above, you could also use `np.isnan()` in the place of `math.isnan()`

Answer (score 0):

You could re-construct your list using list comprehension, without the sub-lists having nans:

```
import math

test = [sub_list for sub_list in test if not any(math.isnan(x) for x in sub_list)]
```

If you want to delete from the `test` list 'in-place', you could do this:

```
import math

for (which, sub_list) in enumerate(test[::-1]):
    if any(math.isnan(x) for x in sub_list):
        del test[len(test)-1-which]
```