# What does the `in` operator in Python use for comparison?

Tags: python, python-3.x, equality, membership

I am trying to understand what mechanism is used by `in` to compare the needle and the haystack.

1. `[] in ([],[],[])` is `True`, so it cannot be `is`, because `[] is []` is `False`
2. But `math.nan in ([],[],math.nan)` is `True`, too, so it cannot be `==`, because `math.nan==math.nan` is `False`.

If it is neither `==` (comparison for equal value) nor `is` (comparison for object identity), what is it?

Comment: It is ```in```.

Comment: `__contains__()`

Comment: It's both. `__contains__` on standard collections uses both `is` and `==` (or a C equivalent to that).

Comment: It is essentially equivalent to the math/logic ```contains``` or ```∈```. It checks an iterable object to see if the value you are searching for is ```in``` the object.

Comment: it uses both `is` and `==`, though `is` is an optimization. The assumption being that identity implies equality (which is not a safe assumption actually!)

Comment: @goalie1998 kinda doesn't answer the question, the OP is asking "how is ∈ determined"

Comment: Largely, if not precisely, a duplicate of [Checking for NaN presence in a container](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9904699/364696).

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga The answer below suggests it is `or`, not `and`.

Comment: @DYZ yes, sorry, I didn't mean to imply that it check if something `is `and `==`, I meant it uses both.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga just giving examples OP might already be familiar with, which is why it's a comment, not an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3.6/reference/expressions.html#membership-test-operations) say:

> For container types such as list, tuple, set, frozenset, dict, or collections.deque, the expression x in y is equivalent to any(x is e or x == e for e in y).

So, it's both.

Comment: Anyway to see that using `dis.dis`? Or do you just need to know that when you see `(in)`, it is the implemented as any?

Comment: @dfundako no, `is` is absolutely **not** implemented as `any`. And you couldn't see this with `dis.dis`, it will just show that you are using the binary operator `is`. It is *equivalent* to that.

Comment: @dfundako internally, lists are implemented in C, so you can't see that in `dis`. For non-builtin containers, you can check `__contains__`.

Comment: @dfundako: It's using [`PyObject_RichCompareBool`](https://docs.python.org/3/c-api/object.html#c.PyObject_RichCompareBool) deep in the C layer; you wouldn't see it with `dis`. That's a C optimized test that's explicitly documented to short-circuit for `==`/`!=` based on identity.